# Moving Item from arrows

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The following code should make a controller for a html element from the arrows.

- Right arrow should make it to move right;
- Left arrow should stop the car.

`moveDown()` function should check if the car is moving up and stop the move and make it move down and `moveUp()` should do the same process but to move it up;
The problem is that `moveDown()` and `moveUp()` is not working properly ,could you help me ?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body >

<p id="demo">A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" id="car" style="position:relative;">

<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction);
var left=0;
var interval=0;
var down=0;
var up=0;
function myFunction(e) {
    var car=document.getElementById("car");
  //Move Right
  if(e.keyCode == 39){ moveRight(car);} 
  //Stop Move
  if(e.keyCode == 37){stopMove(car);}
  //Move down
  if(e.keyCode ==40){moveDown(car)};
  //Move Up
  if(e.keyCode==38){moveUp(car)};
}

//Move the car
function moveRight(car){
 //Check if the car is not already moving   
 if(interval==0){
 interval=window.setInterval(function(){ 
     left+=2; 
     car.style.left=left+"px";},
     30);}
}

//Stop Move
function stopMove(car){
 clearInterval(interval);
 //Reset the interval to 0 
 interval=0;}

//Move down
function moveUp(car){
 interval=window.setInterval(function(){
     down+=2;
     car.style.bottom=down+"px";  
     },30);
}

//Move up
function moveDown(car){
 interval=window.setInterval(function(){
     down+=2;
     car.style.bottom=-down+"px";  
     },30);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one is "down + 'px' = it moves it up and the other is "-down +'px'=move it down

Comment: The second one doesn't subtract `down` # of pixels, it sets it to `-down` pixels. I think you may want `-=` instead of `=-`.